# How do I copy class attributes from a dict?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

using python 3.6 on Mac

I have the following class and I want to instantiate it from a dict

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    brand: Optional[str]
```

I need to copy attributes from a dict

```
def copy_from_make_model(self, data: dict) -> None:
    self.brand = data['brand']
```

what happens it the dict does not have a brand key?

Do I need to check for brand key existence for each of MyModel attributes?

What is the Pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will set brand="" if the data dict doesn't have a brand key.

```
def copy_from_make_model(self, data):
    self.brand = data.get("brand", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating your own function to do the conversion, you could use the already Pydantic's `dict` method to accomplish the same.

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    brand: Optional[str]


my_model = MyModel(brand="test brand")
my_model_dict = my_model.dict()
print(my_model_dict)
```

This will give the following result.

```
{'brand': 'test brand'}
```